# How to extract Element value using JavaScript from DOM if i know the XPATH?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I have 2 Xpaths from a DOM :

```
id("viewproduct-emagoo")/div[@class="big-box"]/div[@class="container-top mb10"]/div[@class="left-content"]/div[@class="container-detalii-produs"]/h2[1]
```

and

```
id("viewproduct-emagoo")/div[@class="big-box"]/div[@class="container-top mb10"]/div[@class="left-content"]/div[@class="container-detalii-produs"]/form[1]/div[1]/div[@class="info-box-produs"]/div[@class="disponibilitate-produs"]/div[@class="pret-produs"]/span[1]
```

I want to extract the Element/s value from one of the above xpaths using JAVASCRIPT.

If someone can find an old article about this, pls give me the link.

Comment: i have this code now:     function lookupElementByXPath(path) {
        var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(); 
        var result = evaluator.evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
        return  result.singleNodeValue; 
    } but i think that i have to use an xpath likeid/div/div/class ...;

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to evaluate an XPath expression in Javascript? Or ... ?

Comment: i have that function, but something is wrong

Comment: yes, evaluate and extract information

Comment: The XPath expression that selects all the children of a given element that can be selected using `someExpression` is: `someExpression/node()` . So, just append `/node()` to the expression that selects the wanted element. To get the string value of the wanted element use this XPath expression: `string(someExpression)`

Comment: i dont uderstand what you are saying; i have the 2 xpaths from above, how do i exatract the element value situated at that xpath ?

Comment: I already showed that in my previous comment -- construct a new XPath expression as per my prev. comment and evaluate it.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian - please avoid posting answers merely to provide supplementary or updated information on your question. Instead, update the question and mark it with [EDIT] or [UPDATE] or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an XPath expression selecting an element node with Mozilla or Opera or Chrome or Safari then simply do

```
document.getElementById("form_selected_product_name").value
  = lookupElementByXPath(value).textContent;
```